# Masonry effect not loaded in D7 Masonry Views

Tags: 7, views

I had installed Masonry Views module, along with Masonry module in my Drupal 7 site.
In my view, I can select format as "Masonry", and had updated the details such as column width.
But the output still displays the view like unfomatted list.

In my status report, it shows
jQuery Masonry: 2.1.08
jQuery Update: jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.2

My js file is in: www/mydomain/sites/all/libraries/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js

I had flushed cached, but the masonry effect still doesn't appear. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: do you get an error in the browser developer console or Firebug? To check; load your page with the browser developer console (right click on page > Inspect element) or Firebug open.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you are just updating a `Jquery` version in front end theme but not updating in `admin` theme. Because `views` opens in `admin` theme so you should also update `Jquery` version in it. For getting this work just goto `admin/config/development/jquery_update`  and click on `configure` link in front of `admin` theme, then select the same version of `Jquery` as you selected in `front` theme. Now you can edit the `masonry views` as per your needs and check the result.